# Interraction in Poisson regression

Tags: estimation, interaction, goodness-of-fit, poisson-regression

I'm trying to understand what is happening in my Poisson regression. I have the following variables: Dependent variable: transactions(number of transactions(continuous)). Independent variables: education(years of education (continuous)),sex(binary),health(health status), income(continuous) other than salary, loan(binary(yes no)). i create the following model(model 1 see below).
 What i know: there is over dispersion and 2 variables are not significant at a 95% confidence interval. i know that there is no confounding! and very low correlation between terms
i create a second model with an interaction term. And suddenly everything becomes very significant, except sex. The estimates change. Is this because the interaction term causes confounding? or what would be the explanation? how could i check which model best fits the data?

---------MODEL 1----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
glm(formula = transactions ~ salary + education + factor(sex) + 
factor(health) + income + factor(loan), family = poisson)
Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.9632  -1.9344  -0.6717   0.5504  12.6591  
Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     -0.413667   0.269088  -1.537 0.124221    
salary           0.004367   0.001303   3.352 0.000801 ***
education       -0.010717   0.006005  -1.785 0.074302 .  
factor(sex)1     0.041353   0.027840   1.485 0.137450    
factor(health)1  1.133173   0.030301  37.397  < 2e-16 ***
income           0.149229   0.036047   4.140 3.48e-05 ***
factor(loan)1   -0.140154   0.026550  -5.279 1.30e-07 ***
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)
    Null deviance: 8848.8  on 2226  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 7419.9  on 2220  degrees of freedom
AIC: 11899
Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

-----------------------MODEL 2----------------------------

```
`Call:
glm(formula = transactions ~ salary + education + factor(sex) + 
    education:income + factor(health) + income + factor(loan), 
    family = poisson)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.9828  -1.9270  -0.6606   0.5475  12.6271  

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      -6.663294   1.370830  -4.861 1.17e-06 ***
salary            0.004822   0.001305   3.694  0.00022 ***
education         0.548942   0.120117   4.570 4.88e-06 ***
factor(sex)1      0.043472   0.027839   1.562  0.11840    
factor(health)1   1.130069   0.030289  37.310  < 2e-16 ***
income            0.951831   0.176518   5.392 6.96e-08 ***
factor(loan)1    -0.137008   0.026557  -5.159 2.48e-07 ***
education:income -0.071936   0.015443  -4.658 3.19e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 8848.8  on 2226  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 7397.5  on 2219  degrees of freedom
AIC: 11879

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding that interaction looks a good idea: both residual deviance (-22.4) and AIC (-20) decrease, and you lose just one degree of freedom in model 2.

Edit. As to overdispersion, you can try:

```
> fit <- glm(...)
> y_hat <- fitted(fit)
> z <- (transactions - y_hat) / sqrt(y_hat)
> disp_factor <- sum(z^2) / df.residual(fit)
```

If `disp_factor > 1` then there is overdispersion and you can:

- multiply your standard errors by `sqrt(disp_factor)` to get the proper ones;
- use another family (quasipoisson) or another model (negative binomial).

Comment: Are these the elements which show which model fits best?

Comment: Especially residual deviance. You can think of residual deviance as a goodness of fit indicator, like $R^2$. $R^2$ is $1-RSS/TSS$, i.e. 1 - residual_deviance / total_deviance, the smaller the residual deviance the better $R^2$. In generalized linear models you look at the residual deviance alone: the smaller it is the better is the goodness of fit (NB: but in GLMs residual deviance is _not_ computed as a residual sum of squares.)

Comment: i guess this residual deviance needs to get closer to the degrees of freedom in order for the model to not have over dispersion. is this right? or am i messing up stuff? you said it needs to be smaller,but according to what, or smaller than what?  thank you for your help

Comment: You are messing ;-)
When you add $n$ explanatory variables (and lose $n$ degrees of freedom) you should get a decrease of residual deviace by at least $n$. Here you add an interaction, only one predictor, and residual deviance decreases by more than 20: good. As to overdispersion, I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: any idea why the estimates change when adding the interaction? i mean shouldnt they be the same? that's why i asked is there any possibility of confounding? for the interaction to be a confounding variable therefore messing up some estimates?

Comment: In general, the estimates don't change _only if_ you add a new predictor which is orthogonal to the ones already included (this is a corollary of the [Frisch-Waugh theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frisch-Waugh_theorem)). But $xy$ is barely orthogonal to $x$ and $y$, so you should expect that the estimates change when you add a new predictor, including an interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Interaction means that the effect of one IV on the DV is different at different levels of the other IV. In your case, the effect of education on number of transactions is different at different levels of income. Similarly, the effect of income on number of transactions is different at different levels of education.

The best way to understand the effects is either to graph them or to look at the effects of different levels of income and education, holding all the other variables constant.

You also wrote that there is low correlation among the IVs. That makes me wonder what income and salary are; using their usual definitions, they would be very highly correlated.

As to confounding, I am not sure what that has to do with the present case. A confound is a variable that correlates both with the IV and the DV.

Comment: i am sorry i was not clear. Income other than salary. how can i graph these effects? Is the second model better than the first? When a confounding variable is added, the values of the estimates change( as i know) that is why i thought that this is due to confounding

Comment: As to graphing those effects, you can try `interaction.plot(income, education, transactions)`, but you'd get better results by cutting income in classes, e.g. income = medium/low/high.

Comment: I don't think adding the interaction counts as confounding. The model with the interaction is better. Thanks for clarifying income and salary.